# Using impoted js method returns ..._WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using external lib. I added it to `package.json`:

```
dependencies: {
    ...
    "hello-world": "0.0.1",
    ...
}
```

This lib exports one method

`index.js`:

```
const helloWorld = (name: string) => {
  ...
}
window.helloWorld = window.helloWorld || helloWorld;
export default helloWorld;
```

Now, Im trying to use that in my Angular project.
I added `src/types.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'hello-world';
```

and `tsconfig.json`:

```
  ...
  "files": [
    "types.d.ts"
  ]
```

Then in `app.component.ts`:

```
...
import helloWorld from 'hello-world';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  ngOnInit(): void {
    helloWorld('Bob');
  }
}
```

But im getting:
`ERROR TypeError: hello_world__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...) is not a function`
Importing it like `import { helloWorld } from 'hello-world';` gives the same error.

However when i call `window.helloWorld('Bob')` in debugger console (F12) it works.

Comment: The lib s enhancing the `window` object directly. Try adding the file in the `assets`-Array in the `angular.json`, you do not need to import it as the lib enhances the window object. 

`"assets": ["src/favicon.ico","src/assets","node_modules/path/to/your/file.js"],`

If you add it to the array, you can call `helloWorld('Bob');` without importing anything.

Comment: Does `import * as helloWorld from 'hello-world';`  Work ok, if so you might just be missing -> `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` in you tsconfig. -> https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports

Comment: @Keith `import * as helloWorld from 'hello-world';` gives me the same error